# discord.py: Hide messages from all other users, but the @mention user

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm developing a matchmaking bot for discord. I read through the documentation and looked through stack exchange, I can't find relevant information on this. I'm trying to eliminate clutter and make it easier for a users to accept and decline a matchmaking request. The bot would listen for a "!match @user" and handle the event. I only want the @user to see and accept it and the user that sent the message to see it (obviously). Right now, I believe it's not possible unless it assigns a secret role and deletes these roles after they are finished; this wouldn't be ideal though. Any information or forward to a post, that would help tremendously.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "hide"? @Silent Serenity

Comment: Only the receiving, outgoing and admins can see the message. Other users in the discord channel will not see the message. I don't believe it's possible with the Discord API.

Comment: Me neither. Therefore, you should probably delete the message entirely, while sending a copy of said message to a seperate channel that only the mods are in. Also send a direct message over to the user as a record

Comment: That looks like the only option. Maybe 3 hidden channels for matchmaking when you get a matchmaking request (the @mention). A channel would be revealed for them; unfortunately, this would be off-putting to the user. I will try it and see how the users like it and get feedback. If they don't like it, the only other option would be, not to have it.

Comment: try it, lets see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'll wait a little longer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not currently hide messages for any specific user/role.

You can try 2 approaches:

1. **Send Message in User DMs**
2. **Make a channel and set it permissions for a specific role and assign that role to the user**

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. I'm just going to have a bot delete and make channels upon request. then assign and take away the roles at the end of the matchmaking request.